# How can we give more than three services name in Power Shell script?

Tags: powershell

---------Power Shell Script to fetch Service Status of Multiple Servers------

```
     Get-Service -Name *HRRA*, "SQL Server Reporting Services","SQL Server Reporting Services (MSSQLSERVER)" -ComputerName $Server | 
        Select-Object @{Name = 'MachineName'; Expression = {$Server}},
                      @{Name = 'ServiceName'; Expression = {$_.Name}},
                      @{Name = 'Status';      Expression = {$_.Status}}
    }
    else {
        Write-Warning "Server '$Server' is unreachable"
    }
}
```

----------------------------------------Scenario---------------------------------

When i am giving third Service name ie "SQL Server Reporting Services

> (MSSQLSERVER)" it is not fetching the status from the server saying as
>   **Cannot find any service with service name 'SQL Server Reporting Services (MSSQLSERVER)'**

Comment: are you _certain_ that the _actual_ name is what you show? PoSh often has a display version and then the real one. plus, the services have `.Name` & `.DisplayName` properties ... [*grin*]

Comment: Instead of `SQL Server Reporting Services (MSSQLSERVER)` use `SQLServerReportingServices`. As @Lee_Dailey mentioned, the one which you are using is `DisplayName` and not `Name` property.

Comment: @Lee yes i am sure the names are "HRRADeliveryService","SQLServerReportingServices" and the third service is "SQLServerReportingServices (MSSQLSERVER)"  for the third services it is saying cannot find any service with this name and the third service is in other servers .The server names are given through input csv file.

Comment: @AditiSingh - it appears that `Vivek Kumar Singh` ahd confirmed that you are looking at the `.DisplayName` instead of the `.Name` that you are using in your code.

Comment: @VivekKumarSingh its not working as in other servers names are different.

Comment: That would mean that you don't have the Reporting services running on one of the servers. Are you sure that reporting services is installed on every server which you are passing through csv. If that's not the case, then you would have to either introduce an error capturing mechanism  or separate the servers which have the services installed from the one which don't have it.

Comment: @VivekKumarSingh yes the services are up and running in other servers name is different so it is not reading while the same name is reading for others servers.

Comment: @Lee_Dailey  i have to fetch the status of multiple servers for the same services but for some of the servers there is a slight change in services name, the second service is not giving status for few of  servers as there is a slight change in the services name in some of the servers- The service name is SQL Server Reporting Services (MSSQLSERVER) in rest of the servers.

Comment: @VivekKumarSingh the above code i have shared has all the three names.The third services is same as the second but it is not reading for some of the servers as in other servers the name is different for the same services. Hope i have made clear what is my requirement..

Comment: If that is the case then you can use `-match` operator like `Get-Service  | ? {$_.Name -match "HRRA" -or $_.Name -match "SQL Server Reporting Services"`.

This should suffice if the second and third services are same as you have mentioned.

Comment: @AditiSingh - it seems that `Vivek Kumar Singh` has a good idea on using he `-match` operator. you may also want to try using `-Name '*hrra*'. 'SQL Server Reporting*'` to get the names with wildcards.

Comment: @VivekKumarSingh i am not getting result from -match.

Comment: @Lee_Dailey its not working either.

Comment: @AditiSingh - please see my Answer. it seems to demo how to do what you need done. [*grin*]

Answer (score 0):

here is a demo of the idea of using a regex match of your partial service names. my system has two services with very similar names - `FontCache` & `FontCache3.0.0.0`. my code gets both of those by matching against `fontcache`.

what the code does ...

- fakes reading in a text file of server names
  when ready to use real data, remove the whole `#region/#endregion` section and use `Get-Content` or some other method to get the system names.
- sets the no-repsonse value
- builds a regex "OR" of the partial service names to match
- iterates thru the server list
- tests for a connection to the target system
- gets the full list of services
- filters them for those that match the regex pattern
- builds a PSCO for each service found
- sends it out to the `$Results` collection
- if there was no connection, it builds a PSCO with that info & sends it to the same collection
- displays the collection on screen

at that point, sending it to a CSV or using it later is fairly direct. [*grin*]

the code ...

```
#region >>> fake reading in a list of servers
#    in real life, use Get-Content
$ServerList = @'
LocalHost
10.0.0.1
127.0.0.1
BetterNotBeThere
'@ -split [System.Environment]::NewLine
#endregion >>> fake reading in a list of servers

$NoResponse = '__NoResponse__'
# the verticle bar "|" is regex for "or"
$Regex_SrvcNameList = @(
    'fontcache'
    'remoteregistry'
    'schedule'
    ) -join '|'

$Results = foreach ($SL_Item in $ServerList)
    {
    if (Test-Connection -ComputerName $SL_Item -Count 1 -Quiet)
        {
        # you may want to change the "ErrorAction" to "Stop"
        #    and then wrap the line in a "try/catch" block
        Get-Service -Name * -ComputerName $SL_Item -ErrorAction 'SilentlyContinue' |
            Where-Object {
                $_ -match $Regex_SrvcNameList
                } |
            ForEach-Object {
                [PSCustomObject]@{
                    ComputerName = $SL_Item
                    ServiceName = $_.Name
                    ServiceStatus = $_.Status
                    }
                }
        }
        else
        {
        [PSCustomObject]@{
            ComputerName = $SL_Item
            ServiceName = $NoResponse
            ServiceStatus = $NoResponse
            }
        } # end >>> if (Test-Connection -ComputerName $SL_Item -Count 1 -Quiet)
    } # end >>> foreach ($SL_Item in $ServerList)

$Results
```

output ...

```
ComputerName ServiceName       ServiceStatus
------------ -----------       -------------
LocalHost    FontCache               Running
LocalHost    FontCache3.0.0.0        Stopped
LocalHost    RemoteRegistry          Stopped
LocalHost    Schedule                Running
10.0.0.1     __NoResponse__   __NoResponse__
127.0.0.1    FontCache               Running
127.0.0.1    FontCache3.0.0.0        Stopped
127.0.0.1    RemoteRegistry          Stopped
127.0.0.1    Schedule                Running
BetterNot... __NoResponse__   __NoResponse__
```